# Running OpenOCD fails with jtagRocketConfig

Tags: riscv, openocd, rocket-chip

This is what I get when I try to connect Software RTL simulation and OpenOCD:

```
xPack OpenOCD, x86_64 Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00068-ge1e63ef30 (2020-03-16-05:57)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
Info : Initializing remote_bitbang driver
Info : Connecting to localhost:38000
Info : remote_bitbang driver initialized
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Error: read: count=-1, error=Broken pipe
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Error: failed jtag scan: -4
Error: Unsupported DTM version: 12
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: Target not examined yet

Error: Unsupported DTM version: 12
Error: fflush: Broken pipe
Error: failed: -4
```

I applied the instructions at [8.2.2.1. Creating a DTM+JTAG Config](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advanced-Concepts/Chip-Communication.html#creating-a-dtm-jtag-config).

The following is the content of OpenOCD config file:

```
interface remote_bitbang
remote_bitbang_host localhost
remote_bitbang_port 38000

set _CHIPNAME riscv
jtag newtap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 5

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME riscv -chain-position $_TARGETNAME

gdb_report_data_abort enable

init
halt
```

And this is the command I use to run the simulation:

```
./simulator-chipyard-jtagRocketConfig +jtag_rbb_enable=1 --rbb-port=38000 <TESTNAME>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run OpenOCD.

This is the current content of OpenOCD config file:

```
adapter_khz     10000

interface remote_bitbang
remote_bitbang_host $::env(REMOTE_BITBANG_HOST)
remote_bitbang_port $::env(REMOTE_BITBANG_PORT)

set _CHIPNAME riscv
jtag newtap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 5 -expected-id 0x10e31913

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME riscv -chain-position $_TARGETNAME
$_TARGETNAME configure -work-area-phys $::env(WORK_AREA) -work-area-size 8096 -work-area-backup 1


gdb_report_data_abort enable
gdb_report_register_access_error enable

# Expose an unimplemented CSR so we can test non-existent register access
# behavior.
riscv expose_csrs 2288
riscv expose_custom 1,12345-12348

init

set challenge [riscv authdata_read]
riscv authdata_write [expr $challenge + 1]

halt
```

And this is how I run OpenOCD:

```
REMOTE_BITBANG_HOST=localhost REMOTE_BITBANG_PORT=38000 WORK_AREA=0x1212340000 openocd --command 'gdb_port 0' --command 'tcl_port disabled' --command 'telnet_port disabled' -f openocd.cfg
```

I also installed Verilator (v4.028).